# How to set loop with pause in between each log

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, settimeout

How could I make a loop that pauses for a set amount of time before repeating?
I tried using `setTimeout` inside of a `while` loop but that didn't work.

Comment: Is your function an async function, and did you use await? Post your best attempt as there's a few formats for this to be done.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I'd use a recursive function instead of a loop and pause before the iterative call.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is monothreaded, so blocking is to be avoided, that is why so much effort was pourred into the language to standardise `Promise` and add `async` / `await`

This allow to pause code execution without blocking, here how you do it:

```js
// Only available in Node v15+
import { setTimeout as pause } from 'timers/promises'

// if not in node:
const pause = delay => new Promise(s => setTimeout(s, delay))

async function sayHelloEverySeconds() {
  while (true) {
    await pause(1000) // 1 sec
    console.log('hello')
  }
}

sayHelloEverySeconds()
```

But for this exact function, it would be simpler to use `setInterval` directly:

```js
setInterval(() => console.log('hello'), 1000)
```

this will execute the function every seconds

Comment: Where are you getting `timers/promises` from? There's no indication that NodeJS is being used.

Comment: @Andy very true, I'll add a disclamer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use async/await functions or promises or a `while` loop. Call a function and have `setTimeout` call the function again after a set amount of time.

```js
function loop(count = 0) {
  console.log(count);
  setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++count);
}

loop();
```